# Keep the "i" value when adding functions to elements

Tags: javascript, function, loops, element

My case:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(i=0;i<tds.length;i++)
{
    tds[i].onclick = function()
                      {
                          alert(i);
                      };
}
```

Expected outcome: Alert the number of TD.

However if there are 6 TDs, the returned value will always be the last value of "i". (6)
How could i make the "i" value to remain at it's value when added to the function?

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/nuKEK/11/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Just a note: your fiddle's JS uses `.getElementsByTagname`, which is a misspelling of `.getElementsByTagName` (capitalized `Name` at the end). The misspelling causes an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a closure to capture the `i` value.  Something like this

```
function createFunction(i){
    return function(){
        alert(i);
    };
}

var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(i=0;i<tds.length;i++){
    tds[i].onclick = createFunction(i);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nuKEK/12/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `i` to another function in order to get its *value* rather than a *reference to it*. In javascript, numbers are passed by value.

```
tds[i].onclick = (function(x) {
    return function() {
        alert(x); // alerting x, i's value
    };
})(i); // passing i as parameter x
```

If that self-executing anonymous function looks a little hairy in the context of your loop, you could try [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("td"), function(td, i) {
    td.onclick = function() {
        alert(i);
    };
});
```

**[edit]** Have a look at [these options and their performance](http://jsperf.com/loop-var-persistence).

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the common mistakes in Javascript in that it is not block scoped like most languages. It is function-scoped.

You need to create a closure around the onclick to achieve this.

```
for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {

    (function (index) {
        tds[index].onclick = function() {
            alert(index);
        };
    })(i);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(i=0;i<tds.length;i++)
{
    addClick(tds, i);
}


function addClick(where, i) {
    where[i].onclick = function()
    {
        alert(i);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to force the value into a scope that will still exist when the callback is fired.

```
for(i=0;i<tds.length;i++){
  (function(){
    var _i = i;
    tds[i].onclick = function(){
      alert(_i);
    };
  })();
}
```

Otherwise, the value for `i` will always be the last index